# Run application after startup and wake up, before user login?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate, task-scheduler

My desktop computer is in my home and I'm in a travel to other cities. I want to access my desktop by remote desktop function in Windows in case I have to retrieve the files in the desktop.

There are no other people in my home, so the simplest method - ask my family member to turn on the computer and tell me the ip- doesn't work.

To save energy, I don't want the desktop be powered on all the time. I can set BIOS of the desktop to periodically powered on and use other methods to hibernate it.

My desktop obtains Internet ip address, which is dymanicaly allocated. As long as I get the ip, I can access the computer. My account in the desktop is protected by password.

I need a solution that when my desktop starts up or wakes up, it runs "sendip.exe", which will send the ip to my email box.

Someone says to build a service. I think it may be overkill.

Someone says to use Task Scheduler and attach task to system events. It looks promising but I don't know exactly which events(startup and wakeup) to attach.

The OS of the desktop is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about upgrading your home router to send your IP to a dynamic IP service (like [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com)), then port forward your router and have your computer turn on from network activity? That's what I ended up doing. Upgrade router with either firmware like [DDWRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) or buy a  new stock unit that has Dynamic IP address services built in - My [Belkin](http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/page/a_id/44) does.

Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Task Scheduler > New Basic Task.

For your answer, create a new scheduled task. Set it to run when Windows starts. Set the executable as your program.

It can be set to wake up your computer, update your IP, then put your computer to sleep using a simple script (run `cmd.exe /c shutdown /h` to hibernate your computer - You can't sleep from command line AFAIK). Scheduled tasks can be set up to wake up a computer from sleep or hibernate, as long as your BIOS supports it.

I'd also set up your computer to wake on network activity. One more note - Make sure your port forwarding on your router is odd - Don't forward any ports under 10000 - I've used 59000 for VNC (don't use VNC - this was the 90s). I'd also recommend a VPN on your home computer, then you connect to the VPN, then RDP into the computer. It's not safe to RDP in the clear.

Comment: I don't have my own router. I use wireless connection provided by the building. I have no way to access the router of the building. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries - Use the second part-- Create a scheduled task. That should do it.

Comment: Oh - Make sure you open the properties once it's created and set it's login information. It needs to run as your user account in order to access the network (generally).

Comment: So what are the triggers of the task? I think the task should be triggered by startup and wakeup.

Comment: Exactly right. Make sure to test this before you leave, just to be sure.

Comment: No. I mean just set start the task when system "starts"? Does "starts" include wakeup?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11710/discussion-between-loveright-and-matcarlson)